# How to create arraylist of object in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

In java, we can create arraylist of object like this:

```
ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

        Country aBucket = new Country();
        aBucket.setName("Canada");
        aBucket.setCity("Ottawa");
        countryList.add(aBucket);
```

or like this way:

```
ArrayList<Matrices> list = new ArrayList<Matrices>();
list.add( new Matrices(1,1,10) );
list.add( new Matrices(1,2,20) );
```

But how can I get the same things/alternative in SWIFT

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using an Array.
Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) for more information about arrays.

You can use the `append(...)` function to add objects.

```
var array = [Country]() //alternatively (does the same): var array = Array<Country>()
array.append(Country())
array.append(Country())
```

Answer (score 6):

Trying to make the code as close to your example code, this is my answer (requires to have declared Country class somewhere:

```
var countryList : Array<Country> = Array()
var aBucket     : Country        = Country()
....
countryList.append(aBucket)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make the code as close to your example code so I use 
the Set data structure :

```
var mSet = Set<Country>()
var aBucket : Country = Country()
...
mSet.insert(aBucket)
```

Answer (score 0):

## A function that returns List

```
func getCountries() -> Array<Country>{

    var countryList = Array<Country>()              //Initialization

    let iceland = Country()                         // Set up
    iceland.name = "Iceland"
    iceland.city = "Reykjavik"

    let usa = Country()
    usa.name = "United States of America"
    usa.city = "New York"

    countryList.append(iceland)                    // Add to list
    countryList.append(usa)

    return countryList                             // Return

}
```

Comment: In the second block of Country you are updating the iceland one...

Comment: Updated @LetynSOFT Good catch